# Auto resize product full image - VirtueMart 2.0

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

For upload image of product is dynamic resizing thumbnail picture but full image uploaded by original width and height.
In settings panel not found parameter for this.

How enable auto resize product full image?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Necessary in the file
administrator\components\com_virtuemart\helpers\img2thumb.php after the line

`$this->NewImgCreate($filename,$newxsize,$newysize,$fileout);` (96) to add:
`$this->NewImgCreate($filename,$newxsize*2,$newysize*2,$filename);`

The size will be twice as many thumbnails!